# Concat values to existing property with LESS?

Tags: css, less

I've this mixin:

```
.if (@condition, @needle, @property, @value) when (@condition = @needle){
    @{property}: @value;
}

.border(@position, @width: 1px, @color: transparent) {
    background-image: linear-gradient(@color, @color);
    background-size: 1px @width;
    .if(@position, bottom, background-repeat, repeat-x);
    .if(@position, top, background-repeat, repeat-x);
    .if(@position, left, background-repeat, repeat-y);
    .if(@position, right, background-repeat, repeat-y);
    background-position: @position;
}
```

Now I'd like to be able to use it multiple times on the same element.
It should simply append the values to the already existing properties.

So, calling it twice, in this way:

```
.element {
    .border(bottom, 1px, @row-border-color);
    .border(top, 1px, @row-border-color);
}
```

should add `background-position: bottom, top;` to the target element.

Is there a way?

Comment: This is most likely a dupe. You should use `background-position+: @position;` within the mixin.

Comment: Aw I wasn't aware about the existence of `+:`!  It's awesome, please put it as answer and I can mark it as correct.

Comment: The question is different, the one you mentioned assumes the reader knows about `+:`, mine is about that operator.

Comment: This one's the closest that I could find - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26890035/less-building-a-string-in-a-loop-for-dynamic-gradient/26908686#26908686. These two seem to be sort of the same though the other one is a bit more complex. I am undecided on whether to write a separate answer. So, will wait for the community to have their say and will post an answer if it doesn't get any dupe close votes.

Comment: It's probably more close to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30644529. (Also as offtopic: I'd rewrite conditionals to be less magic and limited: [gist](https://gist.github.com/seven-phases-max/03bbd5a82c0c502999bf)).

Comment: That's the one I was looking for @seven-phases-max :)